# Should hyper-/hypo- words be tag synonyms of the main tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Maybe the tags `hyperpigmentation` and `hypopigmentation` should be considered synonyms for `pigmentation`? And moreover that could maybe apply on other terms as well.

Comment: Two of them are antonyms so how could they be synonyms?

Comment: I am aware but my suggestions was for the sake of categorizing related subjects. So, when people follow one tag by flagging, they also see the opposite of the related matter. This way we might attract more active users.

Comment: Yeah, I see the value in that, but making antonyms into synonyms seems very misleading. I think the better solution would be to delete the hypo- and hyper- tags and let pigmentation suffice.

Answer (score 1):

As @CareyGregory said in the comments, with your pigmentation example

> I see the value in that, but making antonyms into synonyms seems very misleading. I think the better solution would be to delete the hypo- and hyper- tags and let pigmentation suffice.

However I think you cannot just delete all hypo- and hyper- prefixed tags. The reason is that glycaemia for example can be a misleading tag when applied to questions relating to diabetic levels and therefore the hypo- / hyper- glycaemia tags and similar should stay in my mind.